# Removing a boost::filessystem directory that has had a git_repository cloned to it by git_clone

Tags: c++, git, git-clone, libgit2

I'm using boost::filesystem and libgit2 to clone a git repository to my pc. 
It all works fine until I am finished and try to remove the directory  to which I cloned the repository. 
When doing this I get a R6010 abort(). Here is the code so far.

```
{

    boost::filessytem::path dir("C:/myfolder");

    boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);

    git_repository * repo;
    git_clone_options option = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    options.transport_flags = GIT_TRANSPORTFLAGS_NO_CHECK_CERT;

    int error = git_clone(&repo, gitUrl.c_str(), "C:/myfolder", &option);

    if(error != 0)
    {

    std::cout << giterr_last()->message;
    }

               //i)
    git_repository_free(repo);


    if(boost::filesytem::exists(dir))
    {

    //ii)   boost::filesystem::remove_all(dir);
    }

}
```

i) This line is supposed to free memory used by repo but seems to have no affect on the problem. Whether I use it, git_repository__cleanup, or nothing at all.

ii)This is where the problem is located. The code works when removing a directory that has not had a git repository cloned to it, but when used in this case it crashes.

Comment: Does the error still exist when you don't call libgit2 functions? An error in the boost library shouldn't be related at all. Have you looked at it under a debugger to see what memory access is causing it crash?

Comment: The boost:file system code works fine on its own. It only crashes when trying to remove a directory to which a git repository has been cloned. It ended up being that some files were read only.

Answer (score 0):

`giterr_last()` doesn't allocate or free memory. It returns a pointer to a thread-local static structure.

I'm seeing that you're calling `git_repository_free` on a pointer that (if `git_clone` fails) is uninitialized. It knows how to do the right thing for `NULL`, but it will happily try to derefence `0xdeadbeef` if that's what happens to be in the pointer. This could easily be the cause of your crash.

Not sure why you'd be getting the crash at the place marked `ii`, though, unless your compiler is optimizing away some things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being  libgit2 writing some files as read only. The API wouldn't let boost::filesystem remove them.

Comment: If a read-only file causes boost to fail, then it's still a boost bug,and quite a bad one.